# Como modificar la consulta en un procedimiento almacenado dependiendo de los parametros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola necesito modificar en un procedimiento almacenado la consulta dependiendo a los valores que se entren por parametro

Aqui un ejemplo de lo que estoy intentando pero no tengo resultados:

```
If Exists( Select A.Name From SysObjects A where A.Name = 'sp_iss_APIGetPatientList')
    Drop procedure sp_iss_APIGetPatientList
GO
Create Procedure sp_iss_APIGetPatientList
    @Country varchar(50)

AS

    -- select A.name,A.Code,

   if @Country = 'Uruguay'
      -- add al select A.Country



      -- Al final de todas las condiciones agregar:
         --    from Table A



GO
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente si llega el paramento @Country como 'Uruguay' quieres que se seleccione en el WHERE con ese o que es lo que quisieras hacer en especifico?

Comment: En un select escribo A.name,A.Code pero quisiera que si se cumple la condicion se agregara A.Country es algo como eso

Comment: Que si se pide se ponga algo como A.Country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola esto te puede servir, desconozco la estructura de tus tablas pero te agrego un ejemplo con una tabla temporal.

Cabe destacar que en este caso yo valido si se requieren tu puedes hacerlo de la forma en la que desees el objetivo es darte una idea.

Saludos

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Customers') IS NOT NULL
  begin
  DROP TABLE #Customers
  end

CREATE TABLE #Customers(
IDCustomer INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName VARCHAR(50), 
    LastName  VARCHAR(50),
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(10),
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(50),
    CreationDate DATETIME
)
--Llenamos MIL de datos
;WITH L0 AS (SELECT 1 c FROM(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)c(D)),
      L1 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L0 CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
      L2 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L1 CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
      L3 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L2 CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
      L4 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L3 CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
      L5 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L4 CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
      L6 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L5 CROSS JOIN L5 AS B) --SUFICIENTE PARA UN MILLON

INSERT INTO #Customers (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, CreationDate)
SELECT TOP 1000 REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''), REPLACE(NEWID(),'-',''), 
    CAST( CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*1000000000+4000000000,0) AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(10)),
    REPLACE(NEWID(),'-','') + '@gmail.com',     
    DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 19999 as INT) + 1 ,'2006-01-01')
FROM L6




--DECLARACIÓN DE PARAMETROS PARA SABER QUE CAMPOS INCLUIR DE MANERA DINAMICA
DECLARE @IncludeFirstName BIT=1 ;
DECLARE @IncludeLastName BIT=0;
DECLARE @IncludePhoneNumber BIT=1;
DECLARE @IncludeEmailAddress BIT=0;


--DECLARAMOS UNA VARIABLE QUE TENDRA TODO

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT IDCustomer'


IF @IncludeFirstName=1 
SET @SQL=@SQL+' ,FirstName'

IF @IncludeLastName=1 
SET @SQL=@SQL+' ,LastName'

IF @IncludePhoneNumber=1 
SET @SQL=@SQL+' ,PhoneNumber'

IF @IncludeEmailAddress=1 
SET @SQL=@SQL+' ,EmailAddress'

--Despues de todas las validaciones agregamos el cuerpo

SET @SQL=@SQL+' 
FROM #Customers
'


--Al final ejecutamos la sentecia que hallamos formado

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Te dejo este enlace donde puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=010e371db763502982b9ecfb5d00cf69

Answer (score 1):

Yo me decantaría por una query dinámica también, te lo explico un poco pero es lo mismo que ha dicho Edgar

```
DECLARE @vcSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT A.name,A.Code ' -- Ponemos aquí los atributos que se mostraran siempre ( ojo al espacio final)
IF(@COUNTRY IN ('Uruguay','Perú','Colombia')) -- No me gusta hardcodear pero aquí podrías poner el listado de Paises que provocan que se muestre la nueva columna
BEGIN
    SET @vcSQL = vcSQL+',A.Country '
END
SET @vcSQL = vcSQL+' FROM Table A WHERE...' -- Terminas de construir la query dinámica
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL -- La ejecutas
```

Si te da igual devolverla siempre pero sólo con valor cuando se cumpla una condición determinada puedes usar el case when en la select

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto y me dices como te vá

```
If Exists( Select A.Name From SysObjects A where A.Name = 'sp_iss_APIGetPatientList')
    Drop procedure sp_iss_APIGetPatientList
GO
Create Procedure sp_iss_APIGetPatientList
    @Country varchar(50)

AS
begin
    -- select A.name,A.Code,
   if @Country = 'Uruguay' begin

      -- add al select A.Country

      select A.name,A.Code,A.country 
      from  A
    -- Al final de todas las condiciones agregar:
      end



         --    from Table A
if @Country != 'Uruguay' begin

select A.name,A.Code from A


end

end

GO
```

Comment: Hola no pienso que sea lo mas correcto ya que si tiene digamos 20 validaciones pondrias 20 veces la misma consulta pero con diferentes parametros

Comment: Pues para la pregunta que hizo no ha especificado cuantas validaciones de Paises estaría haciendo, en dicho caso sean muchas el query cambiaría completamente